# Get original data from System.Byte[]?

Tags: c#, android, web-services

Just ran into a problem where I have a webService that returns the photo stored as a base64 string in the database Now the problem is that the service is Returning it has System.Byte[].I am hitting this webService from my android app and I am unable to get the original String.So kindly someone help me sort this Issue out.And please guide me where the change is required webService or in my android app.Thank You.

Comment: It's not really clear what's returning what, or which part is *your* code, I'm afraid. Are you saying your web service request includes the test "System.Byte[]"? If so, you need to fix the web service not to do that. (Why are you storing the photo as base64 in your database instead of just a blob, btw?)

Comment: @JonSkeet The database is already in that way and cant be altered by me.At query level i am getting data correctly but when I am putting it in datatable its getting converted to System.Byte[].any suggestions on this.

Comment: Sounds like there's a problem in some of the code you haven't shown us...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you are asking in C# or Android but this is the solution of Android.

```
String encodedImage; // Your Base64 String
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Comment: The issue is I am not getting the original base 64 string from web service.I am only getting System.Byte[] in string form.

Comment: Have you tried put the that in `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray`?